# Why do I get /usr/bin/ld: internal error ../../ld/ldlang.c 4986 when trying to use default linker script obtained with ld --verbose?

Tags: linux, gcc, ld, gcc7

Do find out where in memory a certain variable is located I wished to create a new section next to .data and then use PROVIDE. The first step was to obtain the current linker script with `ld --verbose` and then use it to link with `-T amd64.ld` (amd64.ld is the file to which I saved the output of ld --vebose) the expectation being that I would get the same final ELF as when no linker script argument (-T) was given. However build fails with /usr/bin/ld: internal error ../../ld/ldlang.c 4986

Using gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0 and GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.30

Anyone knows how to link with the default linker script?

Answer (score 1):

The root cause was that -T was given twice, i.e. -Tamd64.ld -Tamd64.ld